# Html image centering

Tags: html

So I understand how to center images when there is only one
using the css code `block` and `margin` but when I do that the images become on top of each other. I can hardcode the margins by doing `margin-left: 30px` but I also want to consider different screen size will change how the image is positioned. I would want to center it for all screens.

```
#image {
   block:
   margin:
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7TQs/)

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)?

Comment: Not too sure what it that is. I'm reading it right now.
Briefly read it. I don't see how it could hurt

Comment: I asked the question since there are many homeworks are posted here and students are not usually allowed to use features not yet covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach might be to wrap your `a` and `img` elements in a wrapper `div` and apply the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your HTML would look like:

```
<div class="wrap">
<a href="http://www.commnexus.org/evonexus-companies/hush-technology/">
    <img src="http://www.hush.technology/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/evobadge.png" height="75" width="75" id="evonexus" class="evonexus">
</a>
<a href="http://www.sdvg.org/thecool2014/" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    <img src="http://www.hush.technology/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/cool-companies-2014.png" height="75" width="75" id="coolcompany" class="coolcompany">
</a>
</div>
```

You can control the spacing between `a` elements by adding a left margin to the second `a` (or a right margin to the first).

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9LBZ/

**How This Works**

What is needed here is a block level container that can shrink-to-fit the width of the two logos, and `display: table` will do that.  You can then apply `margin: 0 auto` to center the CSS table.

However, to prevent the CSS table from wrapping the two `a` elements into a single narrow column (trying to get the smallest width), you need to add `white-space: nowrap` to keep all the inline `a` elements on a single line.

Comment: Hmm that seemed to work. Do you mind explaining why @Alexander's answer didn't work?

Comment: I posted a detailed explanation for how the proposed solution works.

Answer (score 0):

You could leave them inline elements and wrap them in a container element with `text-align: center` applied. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/94eGf/).

Comment: I've tried this. It wouldn't center. I know it works in fiddle but won't move in wordpress

Comment: @user3281743 You must have some conflicting CSS in your theme.

Comment: @user3281743 - Add `Wordpress` as a tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your image in div then use `float` css property to achieve this :

http://jsfiddle.net/b7TQs/1/

```
.left, .right{
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```